# Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin

I am trying to run a Jmeter test on remote machine ( macOS sierraO).
I configured `jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config` and I can connect to the slave machine. However, whenever I try to run it I get

```
Starting ChromeDriver 73.0.3683.20 (XXXXXXX) on port XXXX
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Mar 08, 2019 12:12:35 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Using local port: XXXXXX
2019-03-08 13:04:39.171 java[10402:23852395] IMKInputSession [0x7f8bcbaaf740 presentFunctionRowItemTextInputViewWithEndpoint:completionHandler:] : [self textInputContext]=0x7f8bcbb578f0 *NO* NSRemoteViewController to client, NSError=Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection from pid 0 was invalidated from this process.}, com.apple.inputmethod.EmojiFunctionRowItem
```

I know this is related to the [security consideration](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations), but I couldn't find a way to solve for my use case.

My use case is:
I am running jmeter test using:

1. Run remote server directly from Jmeter 5.1
2. Run using java-maven-plugin project.

Any thoughts how to configure chromeDriver to run on remote server would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not pass any parameters to `chromedriver` from `p@gc - Chrome Driver Config` directly, my config looks like:

[image: chromedriver config]

where my `chromedriver.dir` was  `chromedirver.dir=vu.chromedriver.dir=/path/to/chromedriver`
However, I was able to work around it by adding:

1. `workaround.sh` for macOS

   `#!/usr/bin/env bash
   /path/to/chromedriver --whitelist-ip $*`
2. `workaround.bat` for Windows

   `\\src\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe --whitelist-ip %*`

And that solved my issue for making chromedriver to accept remote connections.

Comment: Where did you add the file "workoaround.sh"? I'm trying to do the same but I don't know where to put the sh file to execute it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, just make sure the new `${chromedriver.dir} = /path/to/workaround.sh`. You can just add it to the script directory.

Answer (score 8):

lease protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.

Solution: 
Get your Chrome Browser version and download the ChromeDriver for specific to that version.

Open your Chrome browser > Click on 3 vertical dots (top right corner) > Help > About Google Chrome

Verify the Chrome Version (such as 73 or 74 or other ..)

goto Selenium browser driver download portal and download the Chrome Driver of that version

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: For distributed testing, and kicking off webdriver's chrome it won't work.

Comment: I had the same error and fixed by synching my ChromeDriver version with the installed Chrome version, not sure if is the same issue, but worth the shot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed by changing to Chromedriver version 80.0.3987.106