# I am getting this error"Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code"

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I have tried so many times. 
It launches a browser but doesn't perform any other tasks. 
I am using Java 1.8 , chrome Version 80.0.3987.149 (Official Build) (64-bit), chrome driver version 80.0.3987.149. 
I don't know what's wrong I am doing.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0JVY.png)

Comment: the "please protect ports" message is normal.  (The timeout message is the problem...) What you are seeing here might be due to anti-virus or firewall software.  Do you have anything like that installed on the machine?

Comment: ...also check your task manager for currently running chromedrivers/chrome instances before running... sometimes this can be caused by orphaned processes. (or not waiting for one closed browser to finish it's cleanup process....)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55069656/please-protect-ports-used-by-chromedriver-and-related-test-frameworks-to-prevent)

Comment: I have cleared from Task Manager and I have disabled antivirus still not able to do that .. I am receiving "Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100" error

Comment: I would try reverting the driver to v79.  v80 was a little buggy.  If that doesn't help add your full initialization code to your post.  (avoid using screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create chrome driver is by using chrome service with allocating free ports.

```
private static ChromeDriverService service; 
private WebDriver driver; 

@BeforeClass 
public static void createAndStartService() throws IOException {
service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(new File("/path/to/chromedriver")).usingAnyFreePort().build();
service.start();
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(service.getUrl(), new ChromeOptions());
}
```